# How can I create a local user profile for the anonymous user of an ASP.Net MVC application under IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-7, forms-authentication, sql-server-express

I've been experimenting with ASP.Net MVC, and have come across a problem that is probably not specifically MVC related. But I cannot get the authentication in the default MVC application (the one created by the wizard when you create a new MVC project) to work properly under IIS 7 on Windows 7.

If I run under the Visual Studio environment, it works, but if I switch the settings to run under IIS instead, I get the following exception trying to submit the login or registration:

> Failed to generate a user instance of
>   SQL Server due to failure in
>   retrieving the user's local
>   application data path. Please make
>   sure the user has a local user profile
>   on the computer. The connection will
>   be closed.

I believe that this is because the website runs under my own account in Visual Studio, but under the IUSR account in IIS. Google searches on the exception message have been unhelpful so far.

So, can one create a local user profile for the IUSR account? If so, how? Is there something else I should be doing to get the SQLExpress engine to work under the anonymous account in IIS 7?

I also tried configuring the IIS website to use my account, but since this is my home machine, my account doesn't have a password, and it appears that IIS won't let a website be configured to use an account without a password. Or, since this is my first experience with IIS 7, and configuration feels very different than IIS 5/6, I am just missing the right setting that will let me configure the account to use for anonymous access.

EDIT: Some additional information. If I empty the App_Data folder and try again from IIS, SQLExpress attempts to create my database and fails, but the exception message has further information with the following suggestions.

> **SQLExpress database file auto-creation**
>   **error:**
>
> The connection string specifies a
>   local Sql Server Express instance
>   using a database location within the
>   applications App_Data directory. The
>   provider attempted to automatically
>   create the application services
>   database because the provider
>   determined that the database does not
>   exist. The following configuration
>   requirements are necessary to
>   successfully check for existence of
>   the application services database and
>   automatically create the application
>   services database:
>
> 1. If the applications App_Data directory does not already exist, the
>      web server account must have read and
>      write access to the applications
>      directory. This is necessary because
>      the web server account will
>      automatically create the App_Data
>      directory if it does not already
>      exist.
> 2. If the applications App_Data directory already exists, the web
>      server account only requires read and
>      write access to the applications
>      App_Data directory. This is necessary
>      because the web server account will
>      attempt to verify that the Sql Server
>      Express database already exists within
>      the applications App_Data directory.
>      Revoking read access on the App_Data
>      directory from the web server account
>      will prevent the provider from
>      correctly determining if the Sql
>      Server Express database already
>      exists. This will cause an error when
>      the provider attempts to create a
>      duplicate of an already existing
>      database. Write access is required
>      because the web server accounts
>      credentials are used when creating the
>      new database.
> 3. Sql Server Express must be installed on the machine.
> 4. The process identity for the web server account must have a local user
>      profile. See the readme document for
>      details on how to create a local user
>      profile for both machine and domain
>      accounts.

I've pretty extensively confirmed that the first three suggestions have been satisfied. The fourth seems to be the cause of my problems, but I can't figure out how to do that. And although the suggestion claims there is a readme document that describes it, I have not been able to find that document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this problem as well running under medium trust.  The process that creates the database requires at least High trust.  You can check this by looking in your Web.Config for

```
<trust level="TrustLevel" />
```

If there is no trust specified in your Web.Config, try adding it and set it to either Full or High.  If this doesn't work, there is a machine.config in your IIS which you would need to modify.

That being said, the best route I have found to solve this is to just use aspnet_regsql.exe to create the necessary tables and then change the connection string in your Web.Config to look at it directly.

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer, even though it was written almost 2 years ago. I just ran across this problem and that was the only issue of going from "new project" with the default internet application and running it.

Comment: This solved my issue. Make sure to add the element under <system.web>!

Answer (score 1):

I solved "The directory 'LocalApplicationData' does not exist." error when running an SSIS package through an SQL Job by ensuring the SQL SSIS service and SQL Server Agent service were running under the same account as the swql job was set to use!

This in my case was a domain account.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Try UNINSTALLING any updates before you started experiencing the issue.  I spent countless hours - wasted hours that I will never get back in my life - reading and following every solution possible without success.  I uninstalled all SQL Server updates and now everything works fine.

Comment: Egads, No! Do *not* do this under *any* circumstances.